# How to use a BroadcastReceiver from .NET MAUI on Android?

Tags: android, .net, maui

I have existing code from a sample app written for Xamarin.Android (not Forms). I need to use this in my new app written for .NET MAUI, the successor of all Xamarin. It uses a BroadcastReceiver to know when a USB device was detached from the phone. But this doesn't work in MAUI.

Here's the old code:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private BroadcastReceiver detachedReceiver;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        OnScanClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        // TODO: Fix for MAUI
        //register the broadcast receivers
        detachedReceiver = new UsbDeviceDetachedReceiver(this);
        RegisterReceiver(detachedReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceDetached));
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        CloseDevice();

        // TODO: Fix for MAUI
        var temp = detachedReceiver; // copy reference for thread safety
        if (temp != null)
            UnregisterReceiver(temp);
    }

    private async void OnScanClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Here's some code
    }

    class UsbDeviceDetachedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        readonly MainPage mainPage;

        public UsbDeviceDetachedReceiver(MainPage mainPage)
        {
            this.mainPage = mainPage;
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            mainPage.OnScanClicked(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The code below the two TODO comments doesn't compile. I cannot figure out how this should be written for MAUI. Any ideas?

Comment: Actualy, `.net maui` is only the successor of `Xamarin.Forms`. The `Xamarin Native` support (calls to `Android or iOS APIs`) is part of `.net 6` itself. Oddly, googling `.net 6 android` or similar ends up taking you to `maui` blogs and docs - which is not what you need. See [Announcing .NET 6 Preview 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-1/), section "Unified and extended".

Comment: OR if you DO have reason to use MAUI's UI, then the answer is that you put Android-specific calls inside a code block or file that is marked Android. Typically, you define a `Service` there, and then in the cross-platform code, you instantiate the Service, so you can call into it.

Comment: Hm, for this first project, I don't care about cross-platform. I just target Android. But I still don't have the time to learn many different technologies, so I want to learn MAUI and later also target Windows. Android is more important now, I already have WPF for Windows-only. (I have no plans or possibilities to target Apple platforms.) Still, I don't know how to use the code shown above. The called methods don't exist and I didn't want to learn the old tech, too.

Comment: MAUI is the UI part. Its core replaces only the "Forms" part of Xamarin. `Maui.Essentials` (previously Xamarin.Essentials) does include many non-UI services, but can't cover *all* APIs of each platform. Therefore, you must plan on learning some Android APIs. These Android APIs are currently documented as `Xamarin.Android`. Eventually there will be corresponding `.net 6 Android` docs, but those should be identical to the current Xamarin ones. If `BroadcastReceiver` does what you need, then you should continue to use it. You'll just need to learn how to mark that code as only working on Android.

Comment: The `RegisterReceiver` method is defined in the Activity class but I have none. I know that every Android app has at least one but I cannot see it when using MAUI. I couldn't even find out how Forms relates to Activities. Is there one Activity per MAUI ContentPage? Or one for the whole app? Is it accessible somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MAUI, code that in `Xamarin.Android` you would have put in `Activity` lifecycle events, can be done inside `#if ANDROID`, as part of the App Builder. This is documented in [Platform Lifecycle Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle#platform-lifecycle-events).

Example from doc:

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;

namespace PlatformLifecycleDemo
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                    events.AddAndroid(android => android
                        .OnActivityResult((activity, requestCode, resultCode, data) => LogEvent("OnActivityResult", requestCode.ToString()))
                        .OnStart((activity) => LogEvent("OnStart"))
                        .OnCreate((activity, bundle) => LogEvent("OnCreate"))
                        .OnBackPressed((activity) => LogEvent("OnBackPressed"))
                        .OnStop((activity) => LogEvent("OnStop")));
#endif
                    static void LogEvent(string eventName, string type = null)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Lifecycle event: {eventName}{(type == null ? string.Empty : $" ({type})")}");
                    }
                });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In Xamarin.Android docs, we find [Broadcast Receivers in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers).

Its example of using a custom Broadcast Receiver:

```cs
// --- This is Xamarin.Android code, not MAUI code. ---
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity: Activity
{
    MySampleBroadcastReceiver receiver;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        receiver = new MySampleBroadcastReceiver();

        // Code omitted for clarity
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.xamarin.example.TEST"));
        // Code omitted for clarity
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
        // Code omitted for clarity
        base.OnPause();
    }
}
```

---

To keep `MAUI's App Builder` code concise, I would define methods that are called from the builder code:

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
...
#if ANDROID
private static void MyOnCreate(Activity activity, Bundle bundle)
{
    receiver = new MySampleBroadcastReceiver();
}
private static void MyOnResume(Activity activity)
{
    activity.RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.xamarin.example.TEST"));
}
private static void MyOnPause(Activity activity)
{
    activity.UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
#endif
```

So that the builder code is always:

```cs
    ...
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            events.AddAndroid(android => android
                .OnCreate((activity, bundle) => MyOnCreate(activity, bundle))
                .OnResume((activity) => MyOnResume(activity))
                .OnPause((activity) => MyOnPause(activity)));
#endif
        });
```

In your case, place your old `OnAppearing` code into `MyOnResume`.

---

---

NOTE: It is possible to use `.net 6` to write an `Android` app, **without** any mention of `MAUI`. That would be almost identical to writing a `Xamarin.Android` app, except for namespace changes.

To create a ".Net 6 Android" app, in VS 2022 (Preview), when "Create a new project", choose **"Android Application (Preview)"**.

Comment: Okay, so I move the `RegisterReceiver` code to the new static methods in the `MauiProgram` class which get an `Activity` as parameter. What activity will this be? Can I assume that there is only one activity per MAUI app? Or will I have to expect different instances being passed here?

Comment: There is only one activity for Maui. You could even store it in a static variable (inside #if ANDROID) if you want. That is safe, because its lifetime is the Maui App's lifetime.

Comment: Thank you, these lifecycle events helped me to get the app's Activity. As it seems, the other events are already available in the `ContentPage` overridable methods like `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing`. I just needed the `Activity` instance for the broadcast stuff. So now my devices list in the view can refresh whenever I attach or detach a USB device and also when I return to the app.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - you have saved my sorry ass (yet again)!